# How to load virtual dom once the data from api are loaded React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I think that my dom loads faster than data do.
I use useEffect to grab my data and store in localStorage

But when my data are loaded I have to refresh the page one more time to display my fetched data
How can I make my dom wait for the data. I tried to use useState and check whether we get the data from API, I put setLoadDom(true) in my useEffect if statement and then display dom if(loadDom) is true otherwise I show Loading...

From api I get
[
{firstName, lastName, id, completed},
....
{}
]

1. sortInOrder - get data and transforms it in array where indexes are [a,b,c,d,...] and the value is an array of all objects where lastName === to the letter. tmp['a'] = [{lastName: "Amanda"...},...]
2. toggleCheckbox - easy to understand, after I toggled checkbox I use localstorage to save my 'checked' status

Functional component

```
  function App() {
     const ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
     const [employeesData, setEmployeesData] = 
     useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) ?? []);
     const [alphabeticalOrder, setAlphabeticalOrder] = useState([]);

const sortInOrder = () => {
let tmp = []
for(let i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length; i++) {
  tmp[ALPHABET[i]] = []
  for(let j = 0; j < employeesData.length; j++) {
    if(employeesData[j]['lastName'][0].toLowerCase() === ALPHABET[i]) {
      tmp[ALPHABET[i]].push(employeesData[j])
    }
  }
}
for(let i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length; i++) {
  if (tmp[ALPHABET[i]].length === 0) {
    tmp[ALPHABET[i]] = ['-']
  }
}
return tmp
}

const toggleCheckbox = (e, el)  => {
 let checked = e.target.checked;
 setEmployeesData(
    employeesData.map(person => {
      if(person['id'] === el['id']) {
        person['completed'] = checked;
      }
      return person;
    })
)
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(employeesData))
setAlphabeticalOrder(sortInOrder())
}

useEffect(() => {
 axios.get('example.com')
    .then(res => {
      let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) ?? []
      if(res.data.length !== data.length) {
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(res.data.map(el => ({...el, completed: false}))))
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error occured', e))

setAlphabeticalOrder(sortInOrder())
}, [])




 return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="employees">
            <div className="employees_title align">Employees</div>
            <div className="employees_info_block">
              {ALPHABET.map((letter, i) => (
                  <div className="employees_block" key={letter}>
                    <div className="employee_letter" key={i}>{letter}</div>
                    {[...alphabeticalOrder[letter] ?? []].map(el => {
                      if (el[0] != '-') {
                        return (
                            <div className="info_field" key={el["id"]}>
                              <input type="checkbox" checked={el['completed'] ?? false}
                                     onChange={(e) => toggleCheckbox(e, el)}/>
                              <div className="info_field_text">{el["firstName"]} {el["lastName"]}</div>
                            </div>
                        )
                      } else {
                        return (
                            <div>
                              -
                            </div>
                        )
                      }
                    })
                    }
                    <br/>
                  </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="birthday">
            <div className="birthday_title align">Employes birthday</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you post here the full `functional component` of yours?

Comment: @sonkatamas yea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try using `setEmployeesData` after:

```js
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(res.data.map(el => ({...el, completed: false}))))
```

Comment: I thought about triggering useState somewhere because it means that the dom will be reloaded as well

Comment: Definitely you need to use `setState()` to do the comparison and refresh the `DOM`.

Comment: okay, my bad, your answer was correct, thanks